# Sip client for Java

Tags: java, sip

I need to develop java sip client that will

1) receive caller id when the phone is answered.

2) send the caller number along with some information (such as the line that answered the caller) to a given TCP port.

Does anyone have expirience in this field and can advise me where I can find client api or some useful documents?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an article indicating some libraries...

[SIP JAVA API / Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698624/sip-java-api-library)

There is also:

https://java.net/projects/jsip

I have not personally used these but they seem to have decent options for you.